# find_in_set with join in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to get the desire output using laravel query. Tried that way does not get success please guide thanks a lot in advance

Is there any way we can set it in model if possible please guide

```
User

id  name    b_id
1   Alax    1,3
2   Rex     2,4
3   Lex     2,3

Books

id  book_name   book_author
1   Javascript  jim
2   PHP         json
3   LARAVEL     rax
4   SYMPHONY    Alax

Output

id  name    b_id
1   Alax    Javascript, LARAVEL
2   Rex PHP, SYMPHONY
3   Lex PHP, LARAVEL
```

And Query:

```
$res = DB::table('user')->leftJoin('book', function($join){
   $join->on(DB::raw("find_in_set(book.id, user.b_id)",DB::raw(''),DB::raw('')));
});
```

Comment: I hope the book is about Symfony, not Symphony? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$data = \DB::table("user")
        ->select("user.*",\DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(book.book_name) as book_name"))
        ->leftjoin("book",\DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(book.id,user.b_id)"),">",\DB::raw("'0'"))
        ->get();


\DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(book.book_name, ' - ', book.book_author) SEPARATOR ', ') AS book_name_author")
```

Your output looks like.

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object

(

    [items:protected] => Array

        (

            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Alax
                    [b_id] => 1,3
                    [book_name] => Javascript,LARAVEL
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Rex
                    [b_id] => 2,4
                    [book_name] => PHP,SYMPHONY
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Lex
                    [b_id] => 2,3
                    [book_name] => PHP,LARAVEL
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Nice let's say we would like to concatenate two column book_name and book_author then 

\DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(book.book_name) as book_name")) how to concate book_author ?

Comment: Where is a book_author table? I didn't see anywhere in question?

Comment: Just updated the question just wanted to concate author_name as well

Comment: `\DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(book.book_name, ' - ', book.book_author) SEPARATOR ', ') AS book_name_author")` try this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact Laravel syntax problem you are currently facing, but there is a potential problem with your current left join logic.  If a given user have more than one matching book, then he would appear in the result set one time for each match.  This presumably is not what you want, so I would suggest joining using `EXISTS` logic:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM User u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Books b WHERE FIND_IN_SET(b.id, u.b_id) > 0);
```

The Laravel code:

```
$res = DB::table('user u')
    ->whereExists(function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
              ->from('book b')
              ->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(b.id, u.b_id) > 0');
        })
    ->get();
```

The exists approach ensures that each user would only appear once in the result set.