# Failed to get result using laravel query builder to join two table

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables '**users**' and '**channel**'

*Table: users*

```
id  name        channel
1   user1       1,2,3
2   user2       2,3
3   user3       2
```

*Table: channel*

```
id   channel_name
1    IT
2    CS
3    EC
```

I need result as

```
name     channel_name
user1    IT,CS,EC
user2    CS,EC
user3    CS
```

**Using laravel query builder how I write the query?**

I tried below, but I got *channel_name* as *NULL*.

**try 1**

```
$UserChannelList = Users::select('users.name as username', DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(channels.channel_name SEPARATOR ',')) as 'channel_name'"))
        ->leftjoin('channels', function ($join) {
          $join->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET('channels.id', 'users.channel')");
        })
        ->groupBy('users.name')
        ->orderBy('users.name', 'ASC')
        ->get();
```

**try 2**

```
$UserChannelList = Users::select('users.name as username', DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(channel.channel_name SEPARATOR ',')) as 'channel_name'"))
        ->leftjoin('channel', function ($join) {
          $join->on(DB::raw("CONCAT(',', 'users.channel', ',')"), 'like', DB::raw("CONCAT(',','channel.id',',')"));
        })
        ->groupBy('users.name')
        ->orderBy('users.name', 'ASC')
        ->get();
```

Comment: what you get with the 2 attempts?

Comment: You never store data this way. There are no relationships defined between models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this query.

```
\DB::table("users")
        ->select("users.*",\DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(channels.channel_name) as channel_name"))
        ->leftjoin("channels",\DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(channels.id,users.channel)"),">",\DB::raw("'0'"))
        ->get();
```

Please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58334935/9978078)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your solution please check**

```
    $UserChannelList = DB::table('users')
                        ->select('users.name', DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(channels.channel_name)) as 'channel_name'"))
                        ->rightJoin('channels', function($join){
                            $join->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(channels.id, users.channel)');
                        })
                        ->groupBy('users.name')
                        ->orderBy('users.name', 'ASC')
                        ->get();
```